# How to trim white space within Regex using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I've a string and I'm using a RegEx for replacing the string to a specific pattern. Basically I want to trim the white spaces within the named group

For Eg:

```
myString1: substringof('test',Name)
myString2: substringof(' test ',Name)
myString3: substringof('test ',Name)

Expected output: Name.Contains(\"test\")

myString4: substringof(' test test ',Name)
myString5: substringof(' test test',Name)
myString6: substringof('test test ',Name)  

Expected output: Name.Contains(\"test test\")
```

CODE:

```
var replaceRegex = new Regex(substringof\\(\\s*'(?<text>[^']+'?[^']*)'\\s*,\\s*(?<pname>[\\w\\[\\]]+)\\s*\\)");
myString = replaceRegex.Replace(myString, "${pname}.Contains(\"${text}\")");
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why regex and not [trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)?

Answer (score 6):

Use `string.Trim`, but if you insist on Regex:

```
[^\s.*](?<pname>\w.*)[^\s.*]
```

That says not space, then a "word" which can be space separated, then not space.

Another fun way to avoid Regex, and if you want to trim the space BETWEEN words, would be to use string split and join:

```
var text = " name name "; // sample
var result = string.Join(" ", text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: Or just use `(?<=^\s*)\S.*?(?=\s*$)`. The match will be the trimmed string.

Comment: Also good. I prefer to avoid look ahead/behind when I can, but both work.

Comment: `string.Trim` would almost certainly be correct. Any other solution is needlessly complex.

Comment: Exactly why I didn't even look into a solution @Cyborgx37 :P (+1 for both answers though DavidH)

Comment: But needlessly complex approaches are [the spice of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_Perl_Contest), @Sayse!

Comment: Hello all, yes using Trim on the input string is one of the option. But I would like to use it only if regEx is not a feasible option. I shall try above solutions & let you all know. Appreciate your help on this.